# Image Currently Unavailable from Flickr

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flickr

In my Firefox OS app i use Flickr API to show relevant images, My URL for the call is like this.

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&lat=42.86366&lon=-75.91438&radius=3&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
```

and i use created a function to call the flicker api for the images. This is the function where i create the URL with the api key and latitude and longitude for the api call

```
function displayObject(id) {
    console.log('In diaplayObject()');
    var objectStore = db.transaction(dbTable).objectStore(dbTable);
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        if (cursor) {
            if (cursor.value.ID == id) {
                 var lat = cursor.value.Lat;
                 var lon = cursor.value.Lon;
                showPosOnMap (lat, lon);

                // create the URL                   
                var url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search';
                url += '&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
                url += '&lat=' + lat + '';
                url += '&lon=' + lon + '';
                url += '&radius=3';
                url += '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';

                $.getJSON(url, jsonFlickrFeed);

                return;
            }
            cursor.continue();
        } else {
            $('#detailsTitle').html('No DATA');
        }
    };
}
```

This function gets the JSON object received from flickr. This function displays the thumbnails of the images in a jquery mobile grid.

```
function jsonFlickrFeed (data) {
    console.log(data);

    var output = '';
    // http://farm{farmId}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}{size}.jpg
    for (var i = 0; i < data.photos.photo.length; i++) {
        // generate thumbnail link
        var linkThumb = '';
        linkThumb += 'http://farm' + data.photos.photo[i].farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + data.photos.photo[i].server + '/' + data.photos.photo[i].id + '_' + data.photos.photo[i].secret + '_s.jpg';
        // generate Full image link
        var linkFull = '';
        linkFull += 'http://farm' + data.photos.photo[i].farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + data.photos.photo[i].server + '/' + data.photos.photo[i].id + '_' + data.photos.photo[i].secret + '_b.jpg';

        if (i < 20)
            console.log(linkThumb);
        //console.log(linkFull);

        var title = data.photos.photo[i].title;
        var blocktype = ((i % 3) == 2) ? 'c' : ((i % 3) == 1) ? 'b' : 'a';

        output += '<div class="ui-block-' + blocktype + '">';
        output += '<a href="#showphoto" data-transition="fade" onclick="showPhoto(\'' + linkFull + '\',\'' + title + '\')">';
        output += '<img src="' + linkThumb + '_q.jpg" alt="' + title + '" />';
        output += '</a>';
        output += '</div>';
    };
    $('#photolist').html(output);
}
```

Then finally this function show the full screen view of the image. When the user taps on the thumbnail a larger image is taken and shown.

```
function showPhoto (link, title) {
    var output = '<a href="#photos" data-transition="fade">';
    output += '<img src="' + link + '_b.jpg" alt="' + title + '" />';
    output += '</a>';
    $('#myphoto').html(output);
}
```

My problem is that, i get the JSON object with the images by calling the API. i have console.log() where i output the json object and i checked all the image info is there. But when i go to the grid view and even the full view i get the default image that states that the `This image or video is currently unavailable`. I can't figure out what im doing wrong here.. Please help.

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle link?

Comment: Im sorry, what is jsfiddle link?

Comment: Have you checked the link from console.log(linkThumb); to see if it's a good link?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is the site where you can add / update your html / javascript / jquery and share the link to others. So that other can get better idea of your problem.

Comment: Yes, [here](http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2923/14410441660_c9eefe613b_s.jpg) is one such link.. it displays the thumbnail image

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar, I have never used it, what should i do, can you please tell me.

Comment: see [JSFiddle Doc](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html) follow it, it is very easy and useful to describe your problems.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kasunkv/aLAHG/1/) is the link for JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You may be requesting an image size that flickr does not have for that image.  You are appending "_s", "_q" and "_b" to select a few sizes - so perhaps those are not available. You can check the flickr API 'photos.getSizes' to see what sizes are available. The Flickr API seems to be pretty inconvenient sometimes.

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html